# Using Machine.Config and Global Assembly Cache for ActiveX controls - Recommended or not?

Tags: asp.net, activex, gac, .nettiers

I'm currently working with an intranet site which requires the use of an ActiveX control to do some Client side functions. However the app normally reads some settings from the Web.Config (We are using the .netTiers framework).

I've found I can get around this by adding to the machine.config and adding the required DLLs to the Global Assembly Cache, but I'm a little worried this is not an ideal solution. I keep reading about how it's not recommended to use the GAC for such things but I'm not aware of any other approaches to take.

Is anyone able to recommend either way? Thanks in advance.